# How to extract data using two Filters in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am school student and new to the Forum and I need help with some problems.

I have been lately trying to build a Inventory Sheet in Excel, where there is a table of Partnumber, Responsible Department, Delivered Calendar Week and Product type.

I want to filter the data using two filters, for example: The parts that has been taken by customer on calendar week KW(10).

[image: Table]

And I then need to take the total number of this filtered parts to another sheet.

[image: Next Sheet]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you have been "lately trying" then post the results of your labours; what progress have you made? What code?

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) • Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome... As i already i just freshly joined the Forum.. and for you kind information i havent asked anyone to do all the work for me, and yeah i know its not a free code writing service... As you can clearly see from my table how beginner i am in excel, beacuse i am a school student who likes to create something or learn something when i am free.... I was just looking for a hint or clue, how could i connect this things......

Comment: As from your profile, i can clearly see how professional you guys are in this stuffs... i just have an advice for you.... P.S : Be a good Human, before being a good professionals.....

Comment: Well it's no problem if you are new to Excel or VBA but still you can do some research and come up with an idea (we would tell you if this is a completely stupid idea or the right way to go). But if you haven't researched or tried something we have to assume that you did nothing at all yet. This is not about beeing a good or bad guy, but according to [ask] your question is just to broad to answer (actually it is not an actual question as explained in the link). The thing is if you put enough effort into asking a good question people will also put effort into writing a good answer.

Comment: Actually I explained you, that your question was too broad to answer and not a good question but as you might not have realized I still posted an answer at the same time (see below). So there is nothing to complain. Just beeing new or unexperienced doesn't mean the rules explained in the [help] do not apply to you. Still I was patient and posted an answer even your question got 4 close votes by the communitiy because it was not fulfilling the rules.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for VBA. You can use a simple formula for this in the example shown below:

```
=COUNTIFS(Tabelle1[Responsible Department],$F2,Tabelle1[Delivered KW],G$1)
```

Enter this formula in G2 and copy it to the other cells. `Tabelle1` is the name of the formatted table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer... I have already tried this Formula... actually my question was if the sheet contains the data of the whole year, (i.e 52 Weeks) , then i need to write the formula for every shells for the whole 52 weeks... i would try something new , so that i must not put the formula everywhere..

Comment: I wrote this formula only once and then copy/pasted it into the other cells. Excel adjusts the formula automatically.